# Error install mongojs nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongojs

***I'm getting this error when trying to download mongodb . Can you give me an advice please ?***

[image: Error logs npm nodejs mongodb]

After setup pyhton fixed some errors but still have errors about kerberos . Can you help me please ? :

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the relevant error as text rather than an image so it is searchable and a bit easier to read?

Comment: You are right , but i fixed some problem and can't have now old errors log . Sorry for this , i saw your comment very late .

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Dependencies require python executable i faced this problem before installing python solved my problem

Install python from [this link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/python-2.7.10.msi)

Comment: I setup python . Fixed some errors . But still have problems =( Adding last errors under my question . Thank you !!

Comment: Start command prompt as admin might solve some of the permission related issues

Answer (score 0):

Do those errors prevent the Mongo driver from working in your node project? Sometimes those errors can be ignored if the npm package works correctly.

Do you have the full Mongo for Windows downloaded and installed from the Mongo site?

The error also seems to suggest it needs Python installed?

Comment: Actually i'm trying to do  like  this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFsYJG3fGro
I did all steps the same but getting errors . I couldn't get the data from mangodb .

Comment: Ok I see, I didn't watch the whole tutorial but I have an idea of what you're trying to do now.  

So the mongodb driver/package (what you're installing through npm) isn't working correctly when you run it in node?

If you add the error output when you run your node server  that could be helpful.

Do you have mongo for windows correctly installed and the data entered your mongo install?

Comment: db.contactlist.find(function (err, docs){ console.log(docs); res.json(docs);} 
This code is not working . This code in server.js  . I think i gonna download mongodb again . Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: https://github.com/rodrigopolo/node-mongo-demo/tree/master/install_instructions
I using windows 8.1 , in this link writing that i should install Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop. I will try this .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'not working' do you have the error that appears in the console(command prompt) 

Could you either add to this question or make a new question and show your full server.js code and the console error that comes when you run node server.js. This will help people find what is wrong.